# How to open youtube channel page in webview

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube

I know that this question has been asked several time and I had tried several answers but none of them has helped me. I've tried the following answers -

- [html video not playing in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246615/html-video-not-playing-in-android-webview)

[YouTube Video not playing in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706580/youtube-video-not-playing-in-webview)

[YouTube Video not playing in WebView - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708890/youtube-video-not-playing-in-webview-android)

and many others too.

I'm opening a youtube page in my app and the page is showing fine. But when I'm clicking on the video it doesn't play video, I'm only getting the audio.

**Note -** I don't want to play a single video using **iFrame** like others have done. My requirement is to display a youtube page inside a webview where user can browse the list and watch videos, same like what a browser does.

Here is my code -

```
    webView = (WebView) layoutProgressWebview.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("youtube_channel_page");
```

In AndroidManifest.xml file, I've enabled

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: You must enable html 5, please try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3882736/4503373

Comment: @LucaZiegler Thanks How do I enable html5. Can you please tell me because I'm not seeing that on the link that you had given me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

Comment: this is my code its working fine. webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvVideo);
  webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
  webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
  webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

  webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

  webview.loadUrl(vid_url);

Comment: which versions are u targetting. Update webview from playstore.

Comment: Now its working. I just removed my useragent and things are working fine now. Between I was using "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRG83) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1";
as the user agent. Thanks