# How to play video using flutter_webview_plugin

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I'm trying to play video stored in google drive in flutter app. I embed the video and I got the url. when I try to play the video it not work in android while in IOS it works well. Is the plugin don't work will in android or I my way to use plugin is wrong?

```
flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.0+2

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebviewScaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("play video"),
      ),
      url: "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O8WF2MsdyoKpQZE2973IFPRpqwKUjm_q/preview",
      initialChild: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced this issue before, where the video does not play (only audio) on any emulator on android, but does work normally on a real device.

The alternative approach towards playing videos natively on flutter is to use the [video_player](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/video_player) package that enables direct video playing without the use of a webview. Using that, you can play network videos in a much simpler way.

```
 _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'http://yourvideo.com/videolink')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {});
      });
```

Complete example and guideline [here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/video_player).

Comment: I tried to use this plugin with google drive URL but don't work. I got white page [I test it in real device]. I don't no what is the problem

Comment: Try the same thing, but this time load the video from firebase (cloud storage) instead. I think that would be a better approach. Possibly, your Google Drive link doesn't directly return a video file. Rather returns a page that contains the file.

Comment: Basically, the idea is to host it in a location that will return a direct file. When you store it in Google Drive - that doesn't happen. If you have any hosting, that will work too! 

Test it with this [link](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightgallery.js/static/videos/video2.mp4) first, and see if it works. If it does, then you will just need to host your video like this.

Comment: `react-native-webview` has similar or internally related problem not fixed to date: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/172 https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/290

Comment: Similar problems seem to exist in native Android Java WebView: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031908/unable-to-play-video-using-webview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246615/html-video-not-playing-in-android-webview

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution [StackOverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/69961444/11914296) You can use flutter_inappwebview

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I found that the problem was in the link itself. to make it work you will need to change the link like this: you should start the link with: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id= and then add the ID from the original link, and here is a method I made to automate this for you

```
String enableDriveURL(String firstLink) {
var splitted = firstLink.split("/");
var id = splitted[splitted.length - 2];
var firstPart = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=";
var finalURL = firstPart + id;
return finalURL;
```

}
I hope this helped!

Answer (score -1):

You Should Activate The Accelerated Options in Android Manifest Like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J6JN.png