# Flutter - How to play a Google Drive video preview using webview_flutter package

Tags: flutter, webview, video-streaming, html5-video, android-videoview

I have an app that needs to play a Google Drive Video from my account, I'm using this [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin also tried with this too [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin), The thumbnail appears but when I tap play I get the errors below:

```
String url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O8WF2MsdyoKpQZE2973IFPRpqwKUjm_q/preview';

           WebView(
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller){

                  webViewController = controller;

                },
                initialUrl: url,
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                initialMediaPlaybackPolicy: AutoMediaPlaybackPolicy.always_allow,
              ),
```

Errors:

```
 "The deviceorientation events are blocked by feature policy. See https://github.com/WICG/feature-policy/blo
b/master/features.md#sensor-features", source: https://youtube.googleapis.com/s/player/64dddad9/player_ias.vflset/pt_BR/base.js (263)
```

The second time I tap play:

```
I/chromium(29212): [INFO:CONSOLE(1472)] "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Untrusted URL: https://youtube.googleapis.com/videoplayback?expire=158836583
1&ei=x1GsXtyWNuzPj-8Px_eH2Aw&ip=2804:431:c7da:c52b:854e:e83e:e7c5:eb3e&cp=QVNNWkRfVFhRQlhOOk5mQ0FhT0J5Y0k2T3ZDdjJLa0UzQVRiaHNoQlVHeXpjV3BtYW9YT2Rk
YUM&id=eb79141269cc6ad3&itag=18&source=webdrive&requiressl=yes&mh=F-&mm=32&mn=sn-bg0eznll&ms=su&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=47&ttl=transient&susc=dr&driveid=1O8
WF2MsdyoKpQZE2973IFPRpqwKUjm_q&app=explorer&mime=video/mp4&dur=2.043&lmt=1551969798109476&mt=1588351334&sparams=expire,ei,ip,cp,id,itag,source,req
uiressl,ttl,susc,driveid,app,mime,dur,lmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRAIgEzxYGpS8RI0CRVPdZrMxdDGfkYfCezdOkiJ7iUcl5XMCIHiDsmbGel8tWT6XIU8dWdfjLJWdOlI_WHNtDNwYszU9
&lsparams=mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl&lsig=AG3C_xAwRAIgTq3W38roufwBwSPXe4fxB25kANk3s42N5x2oBvVWonoCIDaYJVrPpmNzcoU6q4bqogHP6W-Mw4p_5CRrwh59kZM4&cpn=bCev
241Hx8eXmwyo&c=WEB_EMBEDDED_PLAYER&cver=20200429", source: https://youtube.googleapis.com/s/player/64dddad9/player_ias.vflset/pt_BR/base.js (1472)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews.

Here is the code example using your Google Drive URL and it is working properly:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('InAppWebView Example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: InAppWebView(
            initialUrl: "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O8WF2MsdyoKpQZE2973IFPRpqwKUjm_q/preview",
            initialHeaders: {},
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
              crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                debuggingEnabled: true,
              ),
            ),
            onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
              webView = controller;
            },
            onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
            onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
          ))
        ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Screenshot (.gif):

[image]

Comment: You are a lifesaver.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and I found that the problem was in the link itself.
to make it work you will need to change the link like this:
you should start the link with:
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=
and then add the ID from the original link, and here is a method I made to automate this for you

```
    String enableDriveURL(String firstLink) {
    var splitted = firstLink.split("/");
    var id = splitted[splitted.length - 2];
    var firstPart = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=";
    var finalURL = firstPart + id;
    return finalURL;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Integrate Google Plus Login into your project.
2. created a Google Firebase Project, now it’s time to enable Google Drive API from Google Developer Console.
3. Now, we will add the dependencies for implementing Google Drive Operations (Google API, Pick File to Upload & Download file in mobile storage). Please check below dependencies.

   dependencies:
   flutter:
   sdk: flutter
   cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
   firebase_auth: ^0.15.2
   google_sign_in: ^4.1.0
   flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.1+1
   googleapis: ^0.54.0
   googleapis_auth: ^0.2.11
   path_provider: ^1.5.1
   file_picker: ^1.3.8

Comment: Will authentication solve the error? Because I just want to stream file, the user will not have upload or download option.

Answer (score 0):

The voted answer works but it's outdated so I came up with this solution where I had to go through their documentation and fix it with their current version. Here is the documentation link and here is the link to the documentation [InAppWebView Basic Usage Documentaion](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/in-app-webview/basic-usage/)

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    await AndroidInAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
  }

  runApp(new VideoDetails());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class VideoDetails extends StatefulWidget {

  const VideoDetails(
      {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VideoDetails> createState() => _VideoDetailsState();
}
class _VideoDetailsState extends State<VideoDetails> {
  late InAppWebViewController webView;
  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;
  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  InAppWebViewGroupOptions _options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
        useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
      ),
      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
        useHybridComposition: true,
      ),
      ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
      ));

  late PullToRefreshController pullToRefreshController;
  String url = "";
  double progress = 0;
  final urlController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    pullToRefreshController = PullToRefreshController(
      options: PullToRefreshOptions(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      onRefresh: () async {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          webViewController?.reload();
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          webViewController?.loadUrl(
              urlRequest: URLRequest(url: await webViewController?.getUrl()));
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Some Random Title")),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                InAppWebView(
                  key: webViewKey,
                  initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                      url: Uri.parse(
                          "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-CCTxvNQjayi7gRquNixd7Ss-Qab6G0V/preview")),
                  initialOptions: _options,
                  pullToRefreshController: pullToRefreshController,
                  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                    webViewController = controller;
                  },
                  onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.url = url.toString();
                      urlController.text = this.url;
                    });
                  },
                  androidOnPermissionRequest:
                      (controller, origin, resources) async {
                    return PermissionRequestResponse(
                        resources: resources,
                        action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
                  },
                  shouldOverrideUrlLoading:
                      (controller, navigationAction) async {
                    // var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;

                    return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                  },
                  onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                    pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                    setState(() {
                      this.url = url.toString();
                      urlController.text = this.url;
                    });
                  },
                  onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) {
                    pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                  },
                  onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
                    if (progress == 100) {
                      pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                    }
                    setState(() {
                      this.progress = progress / 100;
                      urlController.text = this.url;
                    });
                  },
                  onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.url = url.toString();
                      urlController.text = this.url;
                    });
                  },
                  onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
                    print(consoleMessage);
                  },
                ),
                progress < 1.0
                    ? LinearProgressIndicator(value: progress)
                    : Container(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ButtonBar(
            alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onPressed: () {
                  webViewController?.goBack();
                },
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                onPressed: () {
                  webViewController?.goForward();
                },
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                onPressed: () {
                  webViewController?.reload();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ])));
  }
}
```